# Another cell's data into current cell w/ additional data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to input numbers, and let sheets calculate the change percentage in the same cell.
For example:

| Oct 20 | Nov 20 | Dec 20 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 100 (+10%) | 95 (-5%) |

Is there a way to it without using additional cells for calculation of the percentage change of previous month?
If not, what's the best way to do so? I assume something w/ cell format..

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I gave the example above. guess it's not that clear. I manually input the 90, 100, 95 values in each cell each month, and I want sheets to calculate the percentage change from previous month

Comment: I think you could only do this with a script, triggered by editing a cell.  The script would take the value you've just typed in, and replace it with a string comprised of the new value plus the percent change from the previous month.  I would think that having the percent change in a separate but adjacent column would be preferable,  For any "reporting view" you could then combine these, but not have them combined on your data entry sheet.  But you must have your reasons.

Comment: A cell cannot contain both a manual input AND a calculation.  One or the other.

Comment: You can do that via a trigger @MattKing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Clearly you need an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) that will run some code whenever you change the value of particular cells in a specific sheet.

The following script:

- Will be activated when you edit a cell in any column except for `A` (which contains the starting value).
- It will calculate the percentage difference based on this formula:

  [image]
- It will return the desired expression back to the edited cell.

### Updated Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet(); // get active sheet
  const rng = e.range;
  const row = rng.getRow(); // get edited row
  const col = rng.getColumn(); // get edited column
  const new_val = rng.getValue(); // get new value
  if (as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col > 1 && row > 1){
    if(new_val!=''){
      let old_val = as.getRange(row,col-1).getValue();
      if(col>2){
        old_val = parseInt(old_val.substr(0, old_val.indexOf(' (')));
      }  
      let c = Math.round(100*(new_val-old_val)/old_val);
      rng.setValue(`${new_val} (${c}%)`);  
    }
    else{rng.clearContent();}
  }
}
```

**How to use it:**

Copy and Paste the code to the script editor. Click on save and then the script will be activated upon edits on "Sheet1" ( remember to **change** the name in the code to the name of your sheet), and on columns B onwards. You **must not execute manually** this function, this is a trigger function and it is executed by itself.

### Illustration:

[image: example]